# "J'ai envie de faire quelque chose pour lui" ou "de lui faire..."

Tags: ordre-des-mots

Choice A: "J'ai envie de faire quelque chose pour lui...."

Choice B: "J'ai envie de lui faire quelque chose...."

Why is the second one is wrong?  Merci pour votre assistance.

Comment: The second one is not wrong, it just means something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same difference as between

> To do something for someone

and

> To do something to someone

Comment: Got it, now that i read them with your translation, I can see the difference.  Thanks, I'll mark this as solved.